# What is Kubernetes API analog for `kubectl auth can-i`

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

`kubectl` has the `auth can-i` subcommand. Which K8s API does the command use? I tried `authorization.k8s.io/v1` `SelfSubjectAccessReview` but it requires the extra permissions to perform the request. Does anybody know how it works in the `kubectl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kubectl auth can-i` command makes the following API request:

```
POST /apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews
```

With a [SelfSubjectAccessReview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#selfsubjectaccessreview-v1-authorization-k8s-io) object as a body parameter named `body`.

You can see this by executing the kubectl command with increased verbosity, for example:

```sh
kubectl auth can-i create pods -v 6
```

And you can find the documentation of the API endpoint in the [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#-strong-write-operations-selfsubjectaccessreview-v1-authorization-k8s-io-strong-).

Comment: Thank you, I do exactly the same in my code, but it is a little bit strange for me that it requires the extra permissions. So I need to grant `create SelfSubjectAccessReview` permission for `authorization.k8s.io` group to the user/role to use it. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly, you need to assign an RBAC role that includes this operation to the user who makes the request. It's an API operation like any other. So users must have permission to check what permissions they have.

Comment: may be you also know, is it possible to check the permissions in a bunch mode? For example, I have 10 permissions to check - is it possible to check it with one API request instead of 10?

Comment: No, you have to make 10 API requests. The only thing you can do is using `*` for "all" in the various fields of the SelfSubjectAccessReview (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#resourceattributes-v1-authorization-k8s-io), e.g. test for all verbs on a resource at once. But you can't check more fine-grained permissions in batch mode.